# SharePoint timer service stopping daily

Tags: 2010, timer-service

Recently we are facing this issue on one of our SharePoint 2010 server. Every morning we restart the service.

I checked below articals, but Service Account is already added in "Log an as Service Account"
[SharePoint 2010 Timer" service needs to be restarted everyday](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1cf30506-4cf6-4d6c-a56d-565a83668c1e/sharepoint-2010-timer-service-needs-to-be-restarted-everyday?forum=sharepointadminprevious)
[SharePoint Timer Service keeps stopping](https://hammadspworld.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/sharepoint-timer-service-keeps-stopping/)

I checked the event logs, there is Timer Service Stop event at 6.13 AM in the morning due to [Timer Recycle Job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/01/10/the-timer-recycle-job-job-timer-recycle/) but there is no any Start event for same.

I have also cleared the timer cache from server, as suggested in below answer of Andy. Still issue persist.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleared the timer cache on all servers in the farm? If not, follow the steps at [http://www.sharepointpitstop.com](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2013/09/clearing-configuration-cache-for.html) on all servers in the farm (perform all steps prior to restarting the timer service on all servers, then go round all of the servers starting the timer job on each of them in turn).

I've also seen this sort of behaviour when a patch has been applied, but the configuration wizard has not been run on all servers (in the case I saw, the configuration wizard had only been run on one server of a two-server farm and the timer service wasn't running on the second server). If this is the case, run the configuration wizard on all servers in the farm to complete the upgrade process on all servers.

Comment: Hi Andy, I cleared the cache from said folder. Let see whether tomorrow timer service auto start or not. I will update you.

Comment: Hi Andy, this does not resolved my issue. Today also I started the timer service.

Comment: What is there in the SharePoint logs for the time at which the timer service should be started? Can you add anything that it related to the question please?